# Google map script doesn't work with empty variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code:

```
function geocode(){
      var country_code ='us';
//    var country_code ='';    
//    if (country_code) var country_code = read_cookie('country');
//    country_code = country_code.toLowerCase();

    var GeoCoded = { done: false };
    var input = document.getElementById('loc');
    var options = { types: [], componentRestrictions: { 'country': country_code } };
```

It is designed to pull the cookie value stored on the users computer and set it to the component_restrictions value for the autosuggest. However, the problem I am having is, if the user doesnt have a cookie set, the value is empty. The componentRestriction only seems to work if there is a value there.

For example if I use this line it works:

```
var country_code ='us';
```

If I use this line it doesnt:

```
var country_code ='';
```

I want it to work so that if there is no cookie set then there is no componentRestriction so it autosuggests all countries. This only seems to work when I remove this code entirely:

```
componentRestrictions: { 'country': country_code } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust options object based on cookie vs no cookie

```
var options = { types: []};

var country_code= read_cookie('country')

if( country_code){
    options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': country_code } ;
}
```